# Using an Array in Excel's Data Validation

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, data-validation

**Problem Statement:**
I am attempting to use data validation to set the criteria of input values within my range of `$C2:$C19`. I am using the **Allow:List** option of Data validation.

**Attempt:**
My attempt for my list is to not use helper cells, but use an array of values instead. My current method that fails is `=$C2={"LATE", "EARLY"}`. I would like to use an array such as this for use as input values.

**Error:**

> You may not use reference operators (such as unions, intersections, and ranges) or array constants for Data Validation criteria.

**Question:**
How can I populate the criteria in a data validation list without the use of "helper cells"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this by just entering the list elements in the dialog box.  I'm using Excel 2011 for Mac.

[image]

[image]

I selected the range C2:C19 beforehand, and all those cells got the same list.

Comment: Me too! Glad to help.